# is 0x0F a 8 bit or 4 bit value?

Tags: binary, port

if I have a port that has only 4 bits, but I am writing 0xFF & 0xF to it. What will happen? Will it truncate the most significant 4 bits or what?

Thanks.

Comment: given you're working with 8bit values in a 4bit space, you'll be subject to big- v.s. little-endian problems. Without knowing your architecture, we cannot say you'll end up with 0xF or 0x0, because it entirely depends on which nibble your system will grab.

Comment: @MarcB, is it reasonable to assume a 4-bit bus? I think endianness has no bearing on this question.

Comment: 0xFF & 0xF = 0x0F. 8bit value, being written to a 4bit port. which nibble goes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that expression (masking with 0x0F) will take the bottom 4 bits from the value. Hopefully your port is connected to the 4 least significant bits of the bus - you'll need to consult the hardware documentation.